# Uploading to specific directory

Tags: php, upload

I've nearly managed to get this upload code working but need help with (hopefully!) the last part.

At the moment the images upload, resize & compress correctly but they end up in one folder and I need to have them end up in a specific location with a specific filename based on a name from my database.

Currently they upload to /images/events/wer34ret.jpg but I'd like them to upload to a numbered folder e.g. /images/events/1045/filename.jpg

It uses 2 pages, resizer.php & uploader.php, I've been playing with session & global variables to try and get the ID into the folder path but it isn't working.

I thought I could just add a variable in like this:

```
if(strtolower($type) == "standard") {
    $path = $location.'/' . $VARIABLE . '/' .$filename;
    imagejpeg($tmp, $path.'.jpg', 90);
```

but the code ignores the variable.  I then tried it with session and global variables but I'm clearly missing something important here.

Here is the code I'm using:

**resizer.php:**

```
function resize ($type,$width,$height,$location,$filename,$key) {

    // Get dimensions from uploaded file

    list($w, $h) = getimagesize($_FILES['uploader']['tmp_name'][$key]);

    // Calculate new size/ratio

    $ratio = max($width/$w, $height/$h);
    $h = ceil($height / $ratio);
    $x = ($w - $width / $ratio) / 2;
    $w = ceil($width / $ratio);

    // Read the binary and create image file

    $imgString = file_get_contents($_FILES['uploader']['tmp_name'][$key]);
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($imgString);
    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $image, 0, 0, $x, 0, $width, $height, $w, $h);

    // Create the path and save the image

    if(strtolower($type) == "standard") {
        $path = $location.'/' .$filename;
        imagejpeg($tmp, $path.'.jpg', 90);
    } elseif (strtolower($type) == "retina") {
        // '@2x' is used at the end of file names to indicate which files are for retina devices
        $path = $location.'/' . $intId .'/' .$filename.'@2x';
        imagejpeg($tmp, $path.'.jpg', 80);
    }

    // Clean up the mess

    imagedestroy($image);
    imagedestroy($tmp);

}
```

**uploader.php**

```
// Configure the uploader's settings

$settings = array (
    'maxFileSize' => 1024*3000, // 3mb
    'allowedExtensions' => array ('jpeg','jpg','png','gif'),
    'variations' => array (
        // thumbnail
        'small' => array(
            'standard' => array(
                'width' => 224,
                'height' => 83,
                'location' => '../../../images/events/'
            ),
            'retina' => array(
                'width' => 448,
                'height' => 166,
                'location' => 'uploads/small'
            )
        ),
        // preview image
        'large' => array(
            'standard' => array(
                'width' => 700,
                'height' => 260,
                'location' => 'uploads/large'
            ),
            'retina' => array(
                'width' => 1400,
                'height' => 520,
                'location' => 'uploads/large'
            )
        )
    )
);

// Include resizer function

require 'resizer.php';

// Create an array to hold the complete upload report

$uploadReport = array();

// Loop through one or more uploaded files
// Currently the HTML file input is restricted to single files but this upload script can handle multiple
// Each uploaded file has an error value, regardless of its success, so we can loop through the errors

foreach ($_FILES["uploader"]["error"] as $key => $error) {

    // Create a report for this file

    $fileReport = array();

    // Determine which error code was produced

    switch ($error) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
            $errorInfo = 'File uploaded successfully';
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            $errorInfo = 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.';
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            $errorInfo = 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.';
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
            $errorInfo = 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.';
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            $errorInfo = 'No file was uploaded.';
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
            $errorInfo = 'Missing a temporary folder.';
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
            $errorInfo = 'Failed to write file to disk.';
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
            $errorInfo = 'File upload stopped by extension.';
            break;
        default:
            $errorInfo = 'Unknown upload error';
            break;
    }

    // Get file details from upload

    $fileName = $_FILES["uploader"]["name"][$key];
    $fileType = strtolower(exif_imagetype($_FILES["uploader"]["tmp_name"][$key]));
    $fileType = getFileTypeString($fileType);
    $fileSize = round(filesize($_FILES["uploader"]["tmp_name"][$key]) / 1000, 2);

    if (!$error === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

        // Upload error detected for this file
        // Store the details in its report

        buildFileReport($fileName,null,$fileType,$fileSize,1,$errorInfo);

    } else {

        // No upload error detected, continue

        // Validate file type

        if (in_array(strtolower($fileType), $settings['allowedExtensions'])) {

            // Validate file size

            if ($fileSize < $settings['maxFileSize']) {

                // Create a unique ID for new filename

                $uniqueFilename = uniqid();

                // Loop through my size variations in settings

                foreach ($settings['variations'] as $variation) {

                    // Loop through the different image types required (retina or standard)

                    foreach ($variation as $type => $item) {

                        // Resize the image and save




                        $strLocation = $item['location'].'/';
                        resize($type,$item['width'],$item['height'],$strLocation,$uniqueFilename,$key);                     
                    }
                }

                buildFileReport($fileName,$uniqueFilename,$fileType,$fileSize,0,"File uploaded successfully.");

                // Return one or the other, or none if you don't want any feedback
                // The first is to return a JSON upload report to the AJAX uploader
                // Use JS to show the report at the AJAX end

                        // echo json_encode($uploadReport);

                // This one returns just the unique filename to the AJAX uploader
                // For this demo, we use the filename on the uploader page to show the preview images

                        echo $uniqueFilename;

            } else {
                buildFileReport($fileName,null,$fileType,$fileSize,1,"File size too big.");
            }

        } else {
            buildFileReport($fileName,null,$fileType,$fileSize,1,"Invalid file type.");
        }

    }
}

// Function to push each fileReport to the uploadReport array

function buildFileReport($name,$newName,$type,$size,$errors,$errorInfo) {
    global $uploadReport;
    $fileReport['name'] = $name;
    $fileReport['newName'] = $newName;
    $fileReport['type'] = $type;
    $fileReport['size'] = $size;
    $fileReport['errors'] = $errors;
    $fileReport['errorInfo'] = $errorInfo;
    array_push($uploadReport, $fileReport);
}

// Function to convert file type codes to strings

function getFileTypeString($fileType) {
    switch($fileType) {
        case "1":
            $fileType = "GIF";
            break;
        case "2":
            $fileType = "JPG";
            break;
        case "3":
            $fileType = "PNG";
            break;
    }
    return $fileType;
}
```

**It uses JQuery on the page:**

```js
            $(document).ready(function() {

                // Clear previews on new upload
                // For demo use

                $('.upload-button').on('click', function() {
                    $('#standard-preview').html('');
                    $('#retina-preview').html('');
                    $('h6').hide();
                    $('#srcset-usage').hide();
                });

                // Uploader starts here

                var formData = false;

                // When file input changes (files chosen), automatically start

                $('#uploader').on('change', function(e) {
                    if (window.FormData) {
                        // User's browser has XHR2 FormData for AJAX uploads
                        // So stop the default behaviour of form submission and AJAX it instead
                        e.preventDefault();
                        formData = new FormData();
                        // When uploader function with AJAX finishes, do stuff with the response
                        // For this demo, the response is the new file name (url) so we can show the examples on this page
                        // We can have a JSON response with details of the uploads instead or nothing if you wish
                        // I've passed 'this' to the function which is the file input object
                        $.when(newUploader(this)).done(function(url) {
                            // This is for this demo.
                            // It shows the example images and resets the progress bar
                            $('h6').show();
                            $('#upload-progress').find('.status').text('');
                            $('#retina-preview').html('<img src="uploads/large/'+url+'@2x.jpg" width="100%">');
                            $('#upload-progress').find('.bar').css('width','0');
                            $('#srcset-usage').find('span').text(url).end().show();
                        });
                    } else {
                        // XHR2 FormData is not available on the user's browser
                        // Se we just trigger a standard form submission instead
                        // Here I ask the user if they want to use the old version but pretty useless really
                        // Just added it for demo purposes to let you know that feature is not available
                        var confirmOld = confirm("Sorry, your browser does not support the latest uploader. " +
                            "Would you like to use the old uploader instead?");
                        if (confirmOld) {
                            $(this).parent('form').submit();
                        } alert("Upload cancelled.");
                    }
                });

                var newUploader = function(fileInput) {
                    // I need to finish this part, as it wasn't required for this demo
                    var i = 0,
                        filesInReader = fileInput.files.length, // this is how many files the user selected
                        img, reader, file;

                    // Loop through files in file input
                    for (i; i < filesInReader; i++) {
                        file = fileInput.files[i];
                        // Make sure it's an image file of some kind
                        if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
                            // This part needs finishing
                            // It allows us to get the filename and size from the user's computer
                            // Handy for showing a list of files being uploaded and a little thumbnail of the file
                            // It's also a fairly new feature, so we check if it's available first
                            if (window.FileReader) {
                                reader = new FileReader();
                                reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                                    // This could call a function that outputs a pretty table of uploading files
                                    //showUploadedItem(e.target.result, file.fileName);
                                };
                                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                            }
                            // Append the current file in the loop to FormData
                            // uploader[] is the name of my file input
                            if (formData) formData.append('uploader[]', file);
                        }
                    }

                    // Here we return the response from the AJAX call to our $.when().done() function above

                    return $.ajax({
                        url: 'uploader.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        cache: false,
                        // This is the function that listens for AJAX progress and calls our renderProgress function
                        xhr: function() {
                            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                            if (myXhr.upload) myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', renderProgress, false);
                            return myXhr;
                        }
                    });
                };

                // Render the progress of our AJAX uploader

                var renderProgress = function(e) {
                    if (e.lengthComputable) {
                        // Find the progress bar
                        var $bar = $('#upload-progress').find('.bar'),
                            progress = Math.round((e.loaded/e.total)*100);

                        // Set the bar with real-time progress
                        $bar.css('width', progress+'%');

                        // This is just making the progress more user-friendly.
                        // As the upload progress finishes when the upload stops,
                        // not when the images have been resized

                        if (progress <= 95) {
                            // If progress less than 95%, show uploading status
                            $('#upload-progress').find('.status').html(
                                '<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Uploading... '+progress+'%'
                            );
                        } else {
                            // If progress greater than 95%, show resizing status
                            $('#upload-progress').find('.status').html(
                                '<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Resizing images... 99%'
                            );
                        }
                    }
                };

            });
```

Comment: `$path = $location.'/' . $VARIABLE . '/' .$filename;` should work, as long as you set `$VARIABLE` to some value and you have actually created that directory before you attempt to save into it

Comment: Thank you @riggsfolly. The directory exists. The $variable is set on the main page but the value is not getting through. I wondered if it was something strange about being in a function that I didn't know about.

Comment: Yes its about variable SCOPE. So variable is not visible in the function, Pass the variable as a parameter on your `resize` function

Comment: I've tried that, I added a global intId into the uploader.php file which should have passed the ID into the resize function but still no joy:
$strLocation = $item['location'].'/'.$GLOBALS['intId'].'/';